# Is there a program to change hex code to assembly code in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm looking for the program which can change hexa code to assembly code in x86?

If you guys know about it, Please leave your comment.

Comment: A program that does that is called a *disassembler* - try searching for that.

Comment: you could use this great online hex editor - https://hexed.it/

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is called "[Disassembler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler)" that translates hex codes into assembly mnemonic. Provide more details on which platform (e.g. Windows, Unix etc.) and which processor architecture (e.g. x86, x64, ARM etc.) you want to do it for.

Here's what I found on [Google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=x86%20dissassembly%20library). Pick one that suits your need. Good luck.

P.S.

[Udis86](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/) looks quite easy to use based on the demonstration on it's homepage.

```
$ echo "65 67 89 87 76 65 54 56 78 89 09 00 87" | udcli -32 -x 
0000000000000000 656789877665    mov [gs:bx+0x6576], eax
0000000000000000 54              push esp
0000000000000000 56              push esi
0000000000000000 7889            js 0x93 
0000000000000000 0900            or [eax], eax
```

[distorm](http://code.google.com/p/distorm/) also looks quite good.

Answer (score 3):

In the Linux world:

```
objdump -dw mybinary
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use debug for this, as per the following transcript:

```
c:\pax> debug

-e 100 eb fe

-u 100 101
0B33:0100 EBFE          JMP     0100

-q

c:\pax> _
```

Of course, that's a fairly limiting option for any but the simplest of programs so you may want to get yourself a decent debugger such as [OllyDebug](http://www.ollydbg.de/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe for little pieces of hex, I use this online service http://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/